# host multiple server block in nginx (https)

Tags: node.js, nginx

My current nginx config look like this

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name api.myapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Which host my production webapp at `api.example.com` but now I need another config for my staging build. I can spin another process of node, make the staging webapp accessible at `http://localhost:3002` but since staging webapp also have to be https so should the second block of config be in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name api.myapp.com;
    ###
    ssl configure
    ###

    location / { 
        if ($server_port = 443) {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        }
        if ($server_port = 80) {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        }
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;   

    }      
}
```

Comment: No, because api.myapp.com is also on https, I don't have to do any ssl config in nginx because it's handled in node app.

Comment: so do you mean the if the user access your website by http, nginx proxy pass http://localhost:3001, nginx proxy pass https://localhost:3002 when user access web by https.  I have change my post following this line of thought.    if i am wrong, i feel sorry for that i might help you more,

Comment: nope, I have 2 app, one is for production, another one is for staging.

Comment: you want to distinguish which app to proxy pass by accessing routes？